# SQL Server - Avoiding write timeouts on logging table due to reporting queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two very busy tables in an email dispatch system. One is for batching mail for dispatch, the other is used for logging. Expensive queries are ran that use both of these tables to produce stats for a UI. I would like to remove the reporting overhead on these tables as I am seeing timeouts during report generation.

My question is - what are my options for reducing the query overhead on these two tables while generating the report data.

I've considered using triggers to create exact copies of the tables. Is there any built in functionality in SQL server for mirroring data within a database? If I can avoid growing the database unnecessarily though that would be an advantage. It doesn't matter if the stats are not real time.

Comment: You could use NOLOCK hint to avoid locks and somewhat improve the performance. However, do this only if your report is not business-critical, as this approach can sometimes introduce errors in your report.

Comment: what are your SQL Server version and edition ?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Web

Comment: I don't understand how triggers can improve performance in your case with out a spool table ( trigger writes PKs to spool table and a job, time by time, takes PKs from spool to replicate to your replicated table).

Comment: The Hardware may also affects the performance of the database. But i guessed you do have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in functionality for this scenario and it's known as [Database Snapshot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx).
If you run a query against a DB snapshot table, no shared locks should be created on original database.

Comment: to add the info : available in Enterprise Edition only

Comment: Thanks for the info, but yes I should have stated edition of SQL Server in use here. Since snapshotting does incur I/O overhead, is there any advantage in using this system over triggers (other than having to code the triggers of course)?

Comment: Yes, you get the out-of-the-box solution. No programming overhead, tested, debugged, optimized. I can't tell if there can be a performance boost over trigger-based solution, never did a comparison myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Resource Governor for SQL Server. Unfortunately, I have only read about it and haven't used it yet. It is used to isolate workloads on SQL Server.
Please try and let us know if it helps.
Some helpful links: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573256.aspx) [SQLBlog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/04/sql-server-simple-example-to-configure-resource-governor-introduction-to-resource-governor/) [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx)

Kind Regards,
Sumit